# Selecting the p tag without any attribute using xpath

Tags: html, xpath

I would like to select only the p tag without any attributes from the following html code.

```
<div id="review">
    <div class="partial_review">
        <div class="1">.....</div>
        <div class="2">
            <div class='inner_Bubble'>
                <div class="entry">
                    <p class="partial_entry>it was a good...</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="full_review">
        <div class="1">.....</div>
        <div class="2">
            <div class='inner_Bubble'>
                <div class="entry">
                    <p>it was a good trip.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried `//div[@class='entry']/p[not class = 'partial_entry']/text()`. But, its not working.

Comment: `//p[count(attribute::*) = 0]` or `//div[@class='entry']/p[not(@class = 'partial_entry')]`. `not` is an XPath function.

Answer (score 3):

If you want all `p` elements with no attributes at all then the simplest path would be

```
//p[not(@*)]
```

If you want to check for the absence of `class` specifically then

```
//p[not(@class)]
```